# How to install an older version of base in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, gloss

I have installed Haskell platform and I have the 7.10.3 version of ghci, which has the 4.8.2.0 version of base. I need to install `gloss-1.8.*` which needs `base-4.7.*` version of base.

My question is how to install this older version now, when I already have the newer version. Is it possible? Or do I have to uninstall the Haskell platform and install an older version?

Comment: well first of all `gloss-1.8.1.*` needs `base == 4.6`, and `gloss-1.8.2` needs `base == 4.7`, but are you aware that the latest gloss version `gloss-1.10.1.1` needs `base == 4.8.*` which you could use. Now the question is - why do you need this old version of gloss?

Comment: You can have multiple GHC versions (with their matching base libraries) installed at once. But you should definitely think about whether you really need that exact version.

Comment: because I found a game in Haskell on the internet, which is created with this version...I want to test it and try to make another starting with this example. Any ideas for my question?

Comment: and how can i install another version?

Comment: You could try editing the game's Cabal configuration to make it use the newer version and see if it works. Sometimes upper bounds go out of date.

Comment: I'm beginner in Haskell..I'm trying to understand how to make a game ..I don't think I can handle with editing configuration..that's why I'm trying to install an old version of ghc with 4.7.* base

Comment: Coroso also if you are using `cabal` to build, you might try the invocation `cabal install --allow-newer` This permits `cabal install` to use more recent versions than the `.cabal` file does. The syntax is pretty simple btw, you just go into the `.cabal` file and look at the `build-depends` or `Build-Depends` stanza(s), and change each `this_package > 0.7 && < 0.9` to `this_package > 0.7`. You must preserve commas - that's as tricky as it gets

Comment: Coroso, oh, and if a range like  `gloss-1.8.* ` is given, change it  to just `gloss` or `gloss > 1.7` or the like. In fact just doing that *may* work if the other dependencies are ok.

Comment: it works. thanks for help

Comment: Is there any reason those knowledgeable about Haskell have refused to answer the question as stated in the title?  If not, could you please answer that question?  If not, could the author please change the title of the question so as not to mislead people searching for the answer?