# How to install Haskell with a "base" specification?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I want to run a program that demands a specific version of the `base` package.  This version is not the one that comes with my OS's version of `Haskell` hence I apparently can't use my OS's version of Haskell.

It would be great of `conda` worked with Haskell the way it works with Python so as to create an environment for a specific version of Haskell, but such is not the case.  Nor is it the case that Haskell's `sandbox` feature permits one to specify a version of `base` let alone Haskell itself.

PS: Frustratingly, the SE question "[How to install an older version of base in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195188/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-base-in-haskell)" ended up answering another question without changing the title to reflect the question it did answer.

Comment: One usually works with haskell-stack to build/... items with a given compiler, library, etc.: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/stack You can see it as some sort of virtual environment like in Python.

Comment: The version of the base `base` is linked to the version of the GHC compiler. If your OS's package manager doesn't have old versions of GHC, you can go the GHC website and install them yourself.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool that works even better then `conda` in Haskell called [`stack`](https://haskellstack.org). Version of `base` is hardwired with version of ghc that is installed. You can get `stack` installed first and it will install version of the ghc you need automatically:

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
```

This command will automatically install ghc-8.6.5, which is specified by [lts-14.22](https://www.stackage.org/lts-14.22) resolver and will make all packages available for you on demand including [`base`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-14.22/package/base-4.12.0.0)

```
$ stack --resolver lts-14.22 ghci
```

To obtain the `resolver` specification:

1. Go to [this table of all packages that come installed with a
   particular GHC version](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/commentary/libraries/version-history).
2. If a desired `base` version is not available, find the scroll bar at
   the bottom of the table and scroll to the right until you find one.
3. Say it is `base-4.11.1.0`, then look at the header of the column for
   the ghc version that ships with this base.
4. In this example either one of this versions of ghc: 8.4.4, 8.4.3,
   8.4.2 will have that version of `base`.
5. Go on the [stackage.org](https://stackage.org) home page and find in
   the matching lastest resolver in the list "Latest LTS per GHC
   version".
6. In this example, any lts-12 will do for the base above.

Latest `nightly` resolver will always have the newest `ghc` and `base` available on stackage.

Comment: How does one translate from `base >=4.8 && <4.9` to a `resolver`?

Comment: @user3673 See the edit I made to the answer: "How to go from base to resolver"

Comment: I edited further to breakout the steps.  However, after following them:

```$ stack --resolver lts-6.35 ghc
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-6.35 specified on command line
Compiler version mismatched, found ghc-8.0.1 (x86_64), but expected minor version match with ghc-7.10.3 (x86_64) (based on resolver setting in ~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml).
Try running "stack setup" to install the correct GHC into ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/```

Comment: If you just want to run `ghc`, the do `stack --resolver lts-6.35 exec -- ghc ...` Normally stack is used to work on full projects. So doing `stack new project-name`, and go from there.

Comment: Also make sure you have newest version of `stack`, not the one provided by the OS.